# Get array of latest minor versions from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, semantic-versioning

I have this array of semver versions:

```js
let versions = ['4.5.0', '4.5.1', '4.5.2', '4.6.0', '4.6.1', '4.6.2', '4.7.0', '4.7.1', '4.8.0', '4.8.1']
```

I want to filter this array and keep only the latest patch versions based on minor and major versions.

Expected result:

```
['4.5.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.1', '4.8.1']
```

I tried to check every version in two loops comparing major and minor versions, but every time I have duplicates and lower versions in the final array.

---

My code:

```js
for (let versions of supportedReleaseList) {
  for (let doubleCheckVersion of supportedReleaseList) {
    if (semver.parse(versions).major === semver.parse(doubleCheckVersion).major) {
      if (semver.parse(versions).minor === semver.parse(doubleCheckVersion).minor) {
        if (semver.parse(versions).patch > semver.parse(doubleCheckVersion).patch) {
           finalList.push(versions);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result was:

```
['4.5.1', '4.5.2', '4.5.2', '4.6.1', '4.6.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.1', '4.8.1']
```

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this. It will work regardless of whether the input list is ordered or not:

```js
const semver = require('semver');

const versions = [
  '4.5.0', '4.5.1', '4.5.2',
  '4.6.0', '4.6.1', '4.6.2',
  '4.7.0', '4.7.1',
  '4.8.0', '4.8.1'
];

const latestMinorVersions = new Map();

for ( const v of versions.map( semver.parse ) ) {
    const baseVersion = new semver.SemVer(`${v.major}.${v.minor}.0`).toString();

    if ( !latestMinorVersions.has( baseVersion ) ) {
        latestMinorVersions.set( baseVersion, v );
    }

    const maxVersion = latestMinorVersions.get( baseVersion );
    const cc         = maxVersion.compare( v );
    if ( cc < 0 ) {
        latestMinorVersions.set(baseVersion, v);
    }

}

console.log(Array.from(latestMinorVersions.values()).map(v => v.toString()));
```

It produces the desired `['4.5.2', '4.6.2', '4.7.1', '4.8.1']`.

**Note that** if your `versions` array contains prerelease and/or build metadata like `1.2.3-beta`, `1.2.3+456`, or `1.2.3.beta+456`, this *may* not work as expected: I would recommend testing those edge cases.